# "Though", "even though" and "although"

Tags: differences, conjunctions

I **do** want to know what is the difference between these three conjunctions.

Are there any differences?

"Though" vs. "Even though" vs. "Although"

Comment: They have different numbers of syllables. Other than that, no difference. However, embedded questions should generally not undergo subject-auxiliary inversion, so your first sentence **should** be _I do want to know what the difference between these three conjunctions is._ If that bothers you, you can extrapose the prepositional phrase: _I do want to know what the difference is between these three conjunctions._

Comment: **Thank you.** I am used to write that way. I don't use this construction because it sounds weird. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They tend to be used in different situations, differing slightly in emphasis. Maybe because some are harder to say.

For instance, if you wanted to make a big deal out of your following statement, you'd say **Although**  or  **even though**.  If it's just a minor issue, then you might say **though**.

If you're going to trail off thoughtfully after the phrase, you would use **although...** or **though...**   I've never heard this with **even though...**.

Also, **even though** emphasizes the "*in spite of the fact that...*"  meaning.

Comment: The ones with more syllables seem more important (this is a general effect, not limited to these choices), and they are also more likely to be fronted and therefore begin a sentence.

Answer (score 0):

*Although* and *Even though* are similar and they had the same meaning. *Although* and *Even though* means "despite in fact that".

Examples:

*Although* Janie didn't study last night, she passed the difficult exam. 
*Even though* Janie didn't study last night, she passed the difficult exam.